# I am trying to make a program to get the time left in my classes but the altered schedule isn't working can you tell me why?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, can you tell me why it isn't working?
It runs by defining the class start/end times but it is only defining the regular time.

```js
//Time Zone variables\\\

var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/New_York"
});
usaTime = new Date(usaTime);
var currentTime = usaTime
var currentDay = usaTime.getDay();
var currentHourET = usaTime.getHours()
var currentHourWT = currentHourET - 3
var currentMinute = usaTime.getMinutes()
var currentSecond = usaTime.getSeconds()
var millisecondsSince = usaTime.getMilliseconds()
var accurateTime = currentHourWT + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond
//Time Zone variables\\
if (currentDay !== 3) {
  var interventionSchedule = confirm("Is it intervention schedule?")
}
if (currentDay = 3 || interventionSchedule == true) {
  //Intervention Schedule\\
  var firstPeriodStart = 29400000
  var firstPeriodEnd = 31800000
  var secondPeriodStart = 32040000
  var secondPeriodEnd = 34440000
  var thirdPeriodStart = 34680000
  var thirdPeriodEnd = 37080000
  var fourthPeriodStart = 37320000
  var fourthPeriodEnd = 39720000
  var homeroomStart = 39960000
  var homeroomEnd = 41160000
  var lunchStart = 41160000
  var lunchEnd = 43080000
  var fifthPeriodStart = 43320000
  var fifthPeriodEnd = 45720000
  var sixthPeriodStart = 45960000
  var sixthPeriodEnd = 48360000
  var seventhPeriodStart = 48600000
  var seventhPeriodEnd = 51000000
} else {
  //Normal Schedule\\
  var firstPeriodStart = 29400000
  var firstPeriodEnd = 32280000
  var secondPeriodStart = 32520000
  var secondPeriodEnd = 35520000
  var thirdPeriodStart = 35640000
  var thirdPeriodEnd = 38520000
  var fourthPeriodStart = 38760000
  var fourthPeriodEnd = 41640000
  var homeroomStart = 41880000
  var homeroomEnd = 43080000
  var lunchStart = 43080000
  var lunchEnd = 45180000
  var fifthPeriodStart = 45420000
  var fifthPeriodEnd = 48300000
  var sixthPeriodStart = 5340000
  var sixthPeriodEnd = 8220000
  var seventhPeriodStart = 8460000
  var seventhPeriodEnd = 11400000
}
///Time Zone variables \\

var minutesFromMidnight = currentHourWT * 60 + currentMinute
var secondsFromMidnight = minutesFromMidnight * 60 + currentSecond
var millisecondsFromMidnight = secondsFromMidnight * 1000 + millisecondsSince

if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= firstPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= firstPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 1
  console.log("It's first period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = firstPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= firstPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= secondPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's first passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = secondPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}

if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= secondPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= secondPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 2
  console.log("It's second period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = secondPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= secondPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= thirdPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = thirdPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= thirdPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= thirdPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 3
  console.log("It's third period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = thirdPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= thirdPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= fourthPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fourthPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= fourthPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= fourthPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 4
  console.log("It's fourth period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fourthPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= fourthPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= homeroomStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = homeroomStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= homeroomStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= homeroomEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 4.5
  console.log("It's homeroom.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = homeroomEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= homeroomEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= fifthPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's lunch!")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fifthPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if ((millisecondsFromMidnight >= fifthPeriodStart) && (millisecondsFromMidnight <= fifthPeriodEnd)) {
  var currentPeriod = 5
  console.log("It's fifth period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fifthPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= fifthPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= sixthPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = sixthPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= sixthPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= sixthPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 6
  console.log("It's sixth period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = sixthPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= sixthPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= seventhPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = seventhPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= seventhPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= seventhPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 7
  console.log("It's seventh period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = seventhPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= seventhPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= firstPeriodStart) {
  console.log("School's over.")
}
```

Comment: Your 'school's over' case doesn't account for the date change, when ms from midnight resets to 0: `else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= seventhPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= firstPeriodStart) {`

Comment: `if (currentDay = 3 || interventionSchedule == true)` should probably be `if (currentDay == 3 || interventionSchedule == true)`, right now currentDay = 3 is assignment, not an equality test

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Time Zone variables\\\

var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/New_York"
});
usaTime = new Date(usaTime);
var currentTime = usaTime
var currentDay = usaTime.getDay();
var currentHourET = usaTime.getHours()
var currentHourWT = currentHourET - 3
var currentMinute = usaTime.getMinutes()
var currentSecond = usaTime.getSeconds()
var millisecondsSince = usaTime.getMilliseconds()
var accurateTime = currentHourWT + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond
//Time Zone variables\\
if (currentDay !== 3) {
  var interventionSchedule = confirm("Is it intervention schedule?")
}
if (currentDay = 3 || interventionSchedule == true) {
  //Intervention Schedule\\
  var firstPeriodStart = 29400000
  var firstPeriodEnd = 31800000
  var secondPeriodStart = 32040000
  var secondPeriodEnd = 34440000
  var thirdPeriodStart = 34680000
  var thirdPeriodEnd = 37080000
  var fourthPeriodStart = 37320000
  var fourthPeriodEnd = 39720000
  var homeroomStart = 39960000
  var homeroomEnd = 41160000
  var lunchStart = 41160000
  var lunchEnd = 43080000
  var fifthPeriodStart = 43320000
  var fifthPeriodEnd = 45720000
  var sixthPeriodStart = 45960000
  var sixthPeriodEnd = 48360000
  var seventhPeriodStart = 48600000
  var seventhPeriodEnd = 51000000
} else {
  //Normal Schedule\\
  var firstPeriodStart = 29400000
  var firstPeriodEnd = 32280000
  var secondPeriodStart = 32520000
  var secondPeriodEnd = 35520000
  var thirdPeriodStart = 35640000
  var thirdPeriodEnd = 38520000
  var fourthPeriodStart = 38760000
  var fourthPeriodEnd = 41640000
  var homeroomStart = 41880000
  var homeroomEnd = 43080000
  var lunchStart = 43080000
  var lunchEnd = 45180000
  var fifthPeriodStart = 45420000
  var fifthPeriodEnd = 48300000
  var sixthPeriodStart = 5340000
  var sixthPeriodEnd = 8220000
  var seventhPeriodStart = 8460000
  var seventhPeriodEnd = 11400000
}
///Time Zone variables \\

var minutesFromMidnight = currentHourWT * 60 + currentMinute
var secondsFromMidnight = minutesFromMidnight * 60 + currentSecond
var millisecondsFromMidnight = secondsFromMidnight * 1000 + millisecondsSince

if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= firstPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= firstPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 1
  console.log("It's first period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = firstPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= firstPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= secondPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's first passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = secondPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}

if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= secondPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= secondPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 2
  console.log("It's second period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = secondPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= secondPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= thirdPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = thirdPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= thirdPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= thirdPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 3
  console.log("It's third period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = thirdPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= thirdPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= fourthPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fourthPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= fourthPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= fourthPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 4
  console.log("It's fourth period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fourthPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= fourthPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= homeroomStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = homeroomStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= homeroomStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= homeroomEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 4.5
  console.log("It's homeroom.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = homeroomEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= homeroomEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= fifthPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's lunch!")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fifthPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if ((millisecondsFromMidnight >= fifthPeriodStart) && (millisecondsFromMidnight <= fifthPeriodEnd)) {
  var currentPeriod = 5
  console.log("It's fifth period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = fifthPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= fifthPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= sixthPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = sixthPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= sixthPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= sixthPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 6
  console.log("It's sixth period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = sixthPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= sixthPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= seventhPeriodStart) {
  console.log("It's passing period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = seventhPeriodStart - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left until class.")
}
if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= seventhPeriodStart && millisecondsFromMidnight <= seventhPeriodEnd) {
  var currentPeriod = 7
  console.log("It's seventh period.")
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMill = seventhPeriodEnd - millisecondsFromMidnight
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftSec = currentPeriodTimeLeftMill / 1000
  var currentPeriodTimeLeftMin = currentPeriodTimeLeftSec / 60
  var timeLeftComplete = Math.ceil(currentPeriodTimeLeftMin)
  console.log("There are |" + timeLeftComplete + "| minutes left in class.")
} else if (millisecondsFromMidnight >= seventhPeriodEnd && millisecondsFromMidnight <= firstPeriodStart) {
  console.log("School's over.")
}
```